# How do I correct prompt SyntaxError?

Tags: python

I created a simple program for a class assignment:

```
>>> print("Ready?")
Ready?
>>> x = "yes"
>>> y = "no"
>>> if "x":
    print("Turn out of driveway, heading west on T Street for .8 miles, while maintaining a speed of 25mph, until reaching the first Stop Sign at the intersection.")


Turn out of driveway, heading west on T Street for .8 miles, while maintaining a speed of 25mph, until reaching the first Stop Sign at the intersection.
>>> if "y":
    print("Then this script isn't for you.")

Then this script isn't for you.
>>> print("Coming to a stop at first Stop Sign, turn right onto U Street and drive for .6 miles while maintaining a speed of 25mph, until you reach the first Traffic Light.")
Coming to a stop at first Stop Sign, turn right onto U Street and drive for .6 miles while maintaining a speed of 25mph, until you reach the first Traffic Light.
>>> print("Once you reach the first Traffic Light, turn left onto V Street and drive for .5 miles while maintaining a speed of 25mph, until you reach the second Traffic Light.")
Once you reach the first Traffic Light, turn left onto V Street and drive for .5 miles while maintaining a speed of 25mph, until you reach the second Traffic Light.
>>> print("Then, once you reach the second Traffic Light, turn right and drive the remaining .1 mile, maintaining a speed of 25mph, until you reach your destination on the right.")
Then, once you reach the second Traffic Light, turn right and drive the remaining .1 mile, maintaining a speed of 25mph, until you reach your destination on the right.
>>>
```

But when I try to run it in Terminal with the command "python3 directions.py", I get the following Sytanx Error:

```
File 'directions.py", line 1
 >>>print("Ready?")
 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've tried a bunch of things and am having difficulty getting somewhere.
I'm sorry if this is basic stuff, I'm just starting to learn Python.

Thank you.

Comment: You should remove >>> on your file.

Comment: @Seo_Hyun Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`>>>` is the repl shell prefix (what you get by running `python3` in the terminal). This symbol is only used for greater than/less than signs, and you should remove it from the start of every line.

Also, `if 'yes'`, `if 'x'`, `if 'y'` and `if 'no'` always evaluate to `True`. You should use an input function - `x = input('yes or no')` and check that: `if x.lower() == 'yes'`.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
answer = input("Ready? yes/no ")
# y/Y or ye?YE or yes/YES are accepted
if(answer.lower() in "yes"):
  print("Turn out of driveway, heading west on T Street for .8 miles, while maintaining a speed of 25mph, until reaching the first Stop Sign at the intersection.")
else:
  print("Then this script isn't for you.")
  # print other output ...
```